# How to catch php form multiple checkboxes values in array & submit with jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pull checkbox values of only checked-checkboxes in a form, using array as name. N then I am using jquery - $.post(), to submit it to action.php file, but its doing nothing then refreshing page. Any guesses, where i am wrong.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("button#ffruits_submit").click(function () {
    var fresorts = $('input[name^="ffruits[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
    $.post("action.php", {fresorts1: fresorts}, function (data) {


    });



    }); // AJAX-FORM SUBMIT ends here

    }); // document-ready ends here

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="ffruits_form" id="ffruits_form" method="post" style="padding:0 0 15px 0px;">

    <table class="sm" border="1px solid #CCCCCC">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `fruitstable` WHERE(fldReadyfordisplay=1 AND fldProductDelete=0) ORDER BY
    resort";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    print('

    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="'.$data['id'].'">
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 15px;">
    '.$data['fruit'].'
    </td>
    </tr>

    ');

    } // while-ends

    ?>
    </table>

    <table style="margin-top: 45px;">

    <tr>

    <td style="padding: 0 15px;text-align: center">
    <button class="myButton" id="ffruits_submit">UPDATE</button>
    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you get the results in console.log(fresorts);add return false at the end of the click function

Comment: add `e.preventDefault();` for prevent refreshing page

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
<button class="myButton" id="ffruits_submit">UPDATE</button>
```

with

```
<button type="button" class="myButton" id="ffruits_submit">UPDATE</button>
```

Add type="button"..its assuming submit button thatswhy refreshing the page.Hope this work.

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

    if( isset($_POST['fresorts1']) ) {
        print_r($_POST['fresorts1']);
        die();
    }

 ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#ffruits_submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            var fresorts = $('input[name^="ffruits[]"]').map(function () { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { return $(this).val(); } }).get(); //@Noman

            $.post(window.location.href, {fresorts1: fresorts}, function (data) {
                alert("Response: "+data);
            });
        }); 
    }); 
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="3">

<button class="myButton" id="ffruits_submit">UPDATE</button>
```

add event.preventDefault(); and see the console log for result

I have updated the code ... put this code in a php file and test

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are hooking the event to the `click` event of the submit button and you're not preventing the default action of the event.

To fix this, hook to the `submit` event of the form and call `preventDefault()` on the provided event. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ffruits_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fresorts = $('input[name^="ffruits[]"]').map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        $.post("action.php", { fresorts1: fresorts }, function(data) {
            // do something here or remove the function
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time

Comment: As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7pfk8bbk/ it works fine. How are you checking the value?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("button#ffruits_submit").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fresorts = $('input[name^="ffruits[]"]').map(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    return $(this).val();
   }
  }).get();
  console.log(fresorts);
  
 }); // AJAX-FORM SUBMIT ends here
}); // document-ready ends here
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="ffruits_form" id="ffruits_form" method="post">
 <table class="sm" border="1px solid #CCCCCC">
  <tr>
   <td style="padding: 15px;">
    <input data-label="checkbox 1" type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="1">
    <input data-label="checkbox 2" type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="2">
    <input data-label="checkbox 3" type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="3">
    <input data-label="checkbox 4" type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="4">
    <input data-label="checkbox 5" type="checkbox" name="ffruits[]" value="5">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table style="margin-top: 45px;">
  <tr>
           <td><span id="respose"></span></td>
   <td style="padding: 0 15px;text-align: center">
    <button type="button" class="myButton" id="ffruits_submit">UPDATE</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

you need some changing in your code

1. when click on button use `event.preventDefault();`
2. when use `.map` set `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {` condition

Check below JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#ffruits_submit").click(function (event) { // clicked event pass by function to prevent redirection of your form submition
        event.preventDefault();
        var fresorts = $('input[name^="ffruits[]"]').map(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                return $(this).val();
            }
        }).get();
        console.log(fresorts);
        $.post("action.php", {fresorts1: fresorts}, function (data) {

        });
    }); // AJAX-FORM SUBMIT ends here
}); // document-ready ends here
```

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time

Comment: @luna.romania it is working fine , it will empty when checkbox is not `checked`

Answer (score 0):

Use this lines in your form.php

```
<div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ac_type[]" value="Checkbox1"/> Checkbox1
            <input type="checkbox" name="ac_type[]" value="Checkbox2"/> Checkbox2
          </div>
```

And in action.php

```
<?php $checkboxtype = $_POST['ac_type'];
          $check_type="";  
          foreach($checkboxtype as $checkbox)  
          {  
            $check_type .= $checkbox.",";  
          }?>
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: I tried everything, var fresorts is empty , all the time